# EF loading entire object graph

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

For some reason EF is loading my entire object graph. I have lazy loading enabled = false on my edmx and am calling `field = db.FormFields.Include("FieldOptions").FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldID == field.FieldID);` but it's loading a couple of other properties hanging off of that along with FieldOptions. How can I turn this off so that not everything is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set lazy loading to `TRUE` if you don't want to eagerly pull down your whole object graph.  That's the whole point of lazy loading—objects are not pulled down until needed.

By setting that to false, you're turning that off, and telling EF to eagerly load associated properties.

Comment: is there a way to turn off lazy loading all together though? when i serialize my object it still loads everything but the performance is worse in this case because of all the additional queries that need to be made.

Comment: How are you serializing it?  If your serialization routine is accessing these properties, they'll be loaded. Maybe that's your problem.  Your serialization routine is causing your whole object graph to be loaded.

Comment: i guess i have to create a new object and copy only the fields i need into it. thanks